# Convert .cshrc to .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, csh

I am new to Linux and I am trying to compile some code that needs environment variables set first.  The script is in cshrc, but whenever I try to run that code I get "if: badly formed number" errors.  I want to run it in bash instead.  Is there an easy way to convert cshrc to bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, post the code. There are hordes of alpha geeks just waiting here to do this sort of work for you, sort of like Rent A Coder but without the cost :-)

Seriously, it's likely to be just the fact that, from memory, `csh` uses parentheses for conditions while `bash` uses `[[...]]` but, until you post the code (at least the offending lines with some context), we can't be sure.

In other words, the `csh`:

```
if ($number < 0) then
    echo What the ...
endif
```

would become the `bash`:

```
if [[ $number -lt 0 ]] ; then
    echo What the ...
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If bash is going to be your preferred shell in Linux, rather than looking for a tool, you might be better served to spend a few minutes learning how to do this in bash. Unless the csh script is *really* complex, it's not likely to take much effort to translate, and having done that you'll be armed with the knowledge to understand future bash (and csh) scripts better.

A couple of tips to get you started:

- in csh, you set environment variables with `setenv`; bash uses `=` + `export`
- the if syntax is different between the two

For example:

```
# bash
if [ ${ORACLE_HOME:-0} = 0 ]; then
    ORACLE_TMP="/tmp"
else
    ORACLE_TMP=$ORACLE_HOME/tmp
fi
export ORACLE_TMP

# csh
if ($?ORACLE_HOME == 0) then
    setenv ORACLE_TMP /tmp  
else                
    setenv ORACLE_TMP $ORACLE_HOME/tmp
endif
```